# How to call LOCK TABLES in mysql database using npm sql package in node js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Is it possible to use sql package in node js to lock mysql table in order to update it and then unlock? I'm writing an API and there will be numerous concurrent connections which will update the database. I tried something like the code below, but after locking the table no further action could be taken on my database.

```
sql.query("LOCK TABLES customers WRITE;", (err, res) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log("error locking: ", err)
  }

  console.log("locked: ", res)
})
```

Comment: Try running SHOW PROCESSLIST in the mysql client while this is blocked. I am guessing the LOCK TABLES is waiting for a metadata lock because there's an outstanding transaction blocking it, and so all other subsequent queries against the customer table are waiting for the LOCK TABLES.

Comment: I think you are right, after removing locking and unlocking part, everything works fine, but when there are lots of concurrent connections to the API, few of them are getting wrong data as they are changing the database at the same time. Do you know any solution for that in node.js?

Comment: I think it has something to do with coding the application the right way. :-) Any more specific answer would need to be based on an understanding of your application logic.

Comment: My application was deployed on heroku and I didn't use postgresql, that's why it wasn't working properly, thanks for your help though